# Jquery Animate Not Working when div is over it

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have a list of images I am trying to animate:

```
<div id = "photoHolderSolutions" class = "PhotoHolder">
    <ul id = "solutionsPhotoList" class = "PhotoList">
    </ul>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
/*
 * Div containing the list of photos
 */
.PhotoHolder
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 559px;
    left: 57px;
    float: left;
    height: 70px;
}

    /*
     * List of photos for each video
     */
    .PhotoList     
    { 
        height: 70px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0;
    }

        .PhotoList li
        {
            list-style-type: none;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
        }
```

The list items are created through Javascript and the animation works fine. I also set all `width` values (`.PhotoHolder` and `.PhotoList`) through javascript to be the width of all the images.I want to hide the extra items that are going to be animated to. So I did this:

```
    <div id = "topPhotoWindowSolutions" class = "TopPhotoWindow">
        <div id = "photoHolderSolutions" class = "PhotoHolder">
            <ul id = "solutionsPhotoList" class = "PhotoList">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

.TopPhotoWindow
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 559px;
    left: 57px;
    float: left;
    height: 70px;
    width: 420px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Assuming that `TopPhotoWindow` would be the container that will hold all the images, and using set `height` `width` and `overflow: hidden` would make only the images I wanted to show up while the lower div `.PhotoList` scrolled through.

Instead what happens is (depending on how I try to work the css) A) All animations stop, and nothing happens (it goes through the method correctly but doesnt move) or B) (happens with this css example) all images disappear)

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you jsfiddle this example?

Comment: Yea, let me see if i can recreate it quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.TopPhotoWindow` is ALREADY placed at `top: 559px` and `left: 57px`

Remember `.PhotoHolder` is INSIDE of `.TopPhotoWindow`

since `.TopPhotoWindow` height is 70px, setting `.PhotoHolder` top to 559px means its outside of the `.TopPhotoWindow` div... which is `overflow:hidden`, so that's why its not showing up.

Comment: Yea I just noticed that.. Setting `.PhotoHolder` to `top: 0; left: 0;` fixed it up

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

- change position to relative on .PhotoHolder
- Try modifying CSS of .PhotoHolder .PhotoList without using TopPhotoWindow HTML/CSS